# Problems with smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this website [toncandigital.com](http://toncandigital.com) with smooth scroll but apparently this ruined my anchor to twitter and facebook in the subscribe section.

I have this code for javascript.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

 $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
 }, 700);
});
```

If you can help me I will appreciate it :P

Comment: Be a bit more specific with click handler, change `.on('click', 'a',...` to `.on('click', 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])',...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restrict the smooth scroll to navigation links like that:

```
$(document).on('click', 'nav.Menu a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 700);
});
```

Comment: You can also specifically target the twitter link: `$().on('click', 'a:not(.my-twitter-selector)', ...)` (Spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: But you probably get hundreds of links on the entire page and it would not be efficient to prevent the click handler for single links. Specifying the nav items should be the better way.

Comment: It definitely depends on the situation @Simon Kraus